# Azure Deployment Pool Agent Fails to install IIS

Tags: azure, iis, installation, devops, agent

**Goal**

I'm trying to install IIS on remote server using azure devops. I have done this on other vm servers without issue.

**Problem**

When running this stage the Agent Errors with very little details
Agent Errors when installing IIS

**Error**

```
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1822182Z ##[section]Starting: IIS Web App Manage
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1984662Z ==============================================================================
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1985052Z Task         : IIS web app manage
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1985379Z Description  : Create or update websites, web apps, virtual directories, or application pools
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1985671Z Version      : 0.5.15
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1985908Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1986227Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/iis-web-app-management-on-machine-group
2020-08-11T19:06:19.1986625Z ==============================================================================
2020-08-11T19:06:21.2180244Z Installing IIS. This may take few minutes.
2020-08-11T19:06:46.1602426Z ##[error]The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed.
The source files could not be found. 
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077. Error: 0x800f081f

2020-08-11T19:06:46.1908491Z ##[section]Finishing: IIS Web App Manage
```

**Stage Settings**

[image]

```
steps:
- task: IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: 'Manage IISWebsite'
  inputs:
    EnableIIS: true
    WebsiteName: 'Default Web Site'
    AddBinding: true
    Bindings: '{"bindings":[{"protocol":"http","ipAddress":"All Unassigned","port":"80","hostname":"","sslThumbprint":"","sniFlag":false}]}'
    CreateOrUpdateAppPoolForWebsite: true
    AppPoolNameForWebsite: default
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by stop trying to use the prebuilt IIS web app manage tool and ended up just installing iis via power shell command

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```